# Lock conditionally

Tags: c#, locking

As far i understand `lock` statement locks the code indiscriminately any subsequent instance that tries to perform this code block.

I need to lock a code block based on the current user (indetified by a userCode). If a user with a different `userCode` tries to perform the code block, it has to let it pass. But if a user with the same `userCode` (previously locked) tries to perform, it has to stop it until the other instance has released it.  How can i achieve this **conditional locking**?

```
private async Task PerformShop(string clientCode){
  lock(clientCode){ //if other user with the same clientCode has locked the block, this current user has to wait. If not, it has to perform code the block.
    performCreditValidation();
    performShop();
  }
}
```

Comment: `lock`ing is really for thread for synchronization. i would avoid doing that based on a specific user. use it appropriately. what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: i want to avoid the same logged user to perform a shop at the same time. For the shop, we have to validate the available credit before shopping, if the available credit changed after validation because the same user has performed the same process from other domain (app or web tab)it can bring problems.

Comment: is this a distributed app in any way - web, desktop + ntier?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, you can access with the same user through app and web. Imagine the same user logged from app and web, then they perform a shop at the same time. Both of them already performed the credit validation but one of them perfoms the shop earlier than the other, it could be a problem because we are based on available credit to allow a shop.

Comment: you should use your database to store that progress and reconcile it there.

Comment: @Walter using `lock` will help only if you have only one instance of your app running (in this case you can for example try using static `ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>` to store lock objects). Otherwise it is harder task.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry i forgot to mention it, the validation is performed in other domain (there is no way to track the database directly) and the shop in other domain.

Comment: @Walter AFAIK you can implement this behavior using Redis [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr)  command for example. Or any other datastore which can perform any atomic "get-or-set" operation.

Comment: @Walter thats alright. you are controlling your apps logic, be defensive.

Comment: You can use `lock(string.Intern("PerformShop" + clientCode))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> White yes, you can access with the same user through app and web. Imagine the same user logged from app and web, then they perform a shop at the same time. Both of them already performed the credit validation but one of them perfoms the shop earlier than the other, it could be a problem because we are based on available credit to allow a shop.

So you got a problem in Web/API development? Lock is *not* even *remotely* the right tool here. As was said, it only deals with thread level synchronsiation.

What you want sounds like "only allow a single active session per user", even if the user might be managing that sesson across multiple devices. It uses the basic session mechanic, but with a twist:

If a User logs in, but a session for that user is still running - he is given that session ID. However that might cause some issues with security as it could keep 1 session alive for a very long time. You realy should re-ask the question with the proper tags.

As a online shop, you might have to deal with even one extra twist - visitors should be able to browse and use the Shopping cart, with or without login. But once they login, their pre-login cart should be recyceled. Wich can cause marge colissions if they were logged in on another device...